# Sublime keep file open but hidden

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I have installed the plugin for SublimeText3 that enables the autocomplete to search through all open files.

I am curious if there is a way to have a file open in sublime in a buffer, like vim, but not actually show open in the editor?

This would make the autocomplete much more effective.